# Docker Node-Red: Keep installed nodes outside container

Tags: docker, npm, node-red, mount

I have to install a lot of missing node-red nodes to the container. Keeping the (named) container and running it with `docker start` works fine.

Now I want to keep the installed nodes in a separate external directory. If I mount `/data` do an external directory it basically works but doesn't help since the nodes are installed in `~/node_modules`. If I try to mount `~/node_modules` to an external directory, node-red can't start.

So what can I do to keep the nodes I installed independent of the executed container?

**EDIT**:
Meanwhile I did run the image as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -E docker run -it --rm -p 1893:1880 -p 11893:11880 
  \ -e TZ=Europe/Berlin -e NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/data/node_modules/ 
  \ -e NODE_PATH=/usr/src/node-red/node_modules:/data/node_modules:/data/node_modules/lib/node_modules 
  \ --log-driver none --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/data,target=/data 
  \ --name myNodeRed nodered/node-red
```

but the additional installed nodes, that are in directory `/data/node_modules/lib/node_modules` are still not visible.

**EDIT 2**:
Meanwhile I tried to keep the container. So it became obvious, that nodes installed using `npm install -g` are fully ignored.

Comment: Why have you turned logging off? Also why have you passed all the NPM/Node_PATH options into the container, there should be no need to move anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default user for the Node-RED instance inside the container is not root (as is usual) so you need to make sure any volume you mount on to the `/data` location is writable by that user. You can do this by passing in the user id to the container to have it match the external user that has write permission to the mount point:

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/data:/data -u $USER -e TZ=Europe/Berlin
 \ -p 1893:1880 -p 11893:11880 --log-driver none
 \ --name myNodeRed nodered/node-red
```

Node-RED nodes should not be installed with the `-g` option, you should use the build in Palette Manager or if you really need to use the command line, run `npm install <node-name>` in the `/data` directory inside the container (But you will need to restart the container for the newly installed nodes to be picked up, which is again why you should use the Palette Manager)

Comment: Thank you. Running npm install in the /data directory was the missing link. I think it is described at least rarely in the web even if so important, in my opinion.